# Prove non-nullness of `get` for iterated keys

Tags: java, checker-framework

- I have an interface which has map-like functionality, but does not implement Java's Map interface.
- The map interface also implements `Iterable<Object>`; it iterates over the keys of the map
- I'd like to use `this` in the body of an enhanced loop (see below), but without an assertion, and use `get` to retrieve values for the iterated keys, and without an `[ERROR]` from the Checker Framework.
- Is that at all possible and could you provide pointers where to start or examples to learn from? I tried haphazardly to sprinkle some `@KeyFor`s here and there, but with a lack of fully understanding what I'm doing it could take a while before I hit the right spots ;-)
- I understand we might use an "Entry Iterator" and avoid to have to solve this problem in the first place, but I'm really just interested in learning how to teach the Checker Framework about the semantic relation between a key iterator and an `@Nullable get` method.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

interface IMap extends Iterable<Object> {
    @Nullable Object get(Object o);
    IMap put(Object key, Object value); // immutable put
    IMap empty();

    default IMap remove(Object key) {
       IMap tmp = empty();

       for (Object k : this) {
           if (!k.equals(key)) {
               tmp.put(k, get(k)); // get(k) is always non-null because of the key iterator
           }
       }

       return tmp;
    }
}

class Map implements IMap {
   java.util.Map<Object, Object> contents = new java.util.HashMap<>();

   public Map() { }

   private Map(java.util.Map<Object, Object> contents) {
      this.contents = contents;   
   }

   @Override
   public @Nullable Object get(Object key) {
     return contents.get(key);
   }

   @Override
   public IMap empty() {
       return new Map();
   }

   @Override
   public IMap put(Object key, Object value) {
      java.util.Map<Object, Object> newContents = new java.util.HashMap<>();
      newContents.putAll(contents);
      newContents.put(key, value);
      return new Map(newContents);
   }

   @Override
   public java.util.Iterator<Object> iterator() {
      return contents.keySet().iterator();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?  Otherwise we have to guess at the types in your example and their definitions.

Comment: Sure, I'll give that a try. May take some time M, since I'm not fully operational.

Comment: I've edited the question to contain the MWE, and tested it at http://eisop.uwaterloo.ca/live/#mode=display. Indeed CF rightly complains about the `get(k)` on line 13 in the default `remove` method. I would like to learn how to teach it the iterator produces keys which will make `get` return non-null values guaranteed.

Comment: It would be more to the point to have your `put()` method throw an NPE if the key is null. Then the situation you are testing cannot possibly arise, and all you have to check is the NPE on `put()`, rather than the iterator.

Comment: Sure, that's also a design, but not what I want to learn about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nullness Checker is warning you that the specifications (the type annotations) are inconsistent with the code itself.

### Nullness problem

The key problem with your code is here:

```
tmp.put(k, get(k))
```

and the error message is:

```
error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
               tmp.put(k, get(k)); // get(k) is always non-null because of the key iterator
                             ^
  found   : @Initialized @Nullable Object
  required: @Initialized @NonNull Object
```

Here are the two specifications that are incompatible:

1. `put` requires a non-null second argument (recall that `@NonNull` is the default):

```
   public IMap put(Object key, Object value) { ... }
```

2. `get` might return null at any time, and clients have no way to know when the return value might be non-null:

```
   @Nullable Object get(Object o);
```

If you want to state that the return value of a method is nullable in general, but is non-null in certain situations, then you need to use a *conditional postcondition* such as [`@EnsuresNonNullIf`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/EnsuresNonNullIf.html).

That said, the Nullness Checker has [special handling for `Map.get`](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#map-key-qualifiers).  Your code doesn't use that, because you don't have a method that overrides `java.util.Map.get` (though it does have a class named `Map` that has nothing to do with `java.util.Map`).

If you want special-case handling for `IMap.get`, then either:

- your class should extend `java.util.Map`, or
- you should extend the Nullness Checker to recognize your class.

### Map key problem

> could you provide pointers where to start or examples to learn from?

I suggest starting with the [Checker Framework Manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/).  It has lots of explanations and examples.  You should read at least the [Map Key Checker chapter](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#map-key-checker).  It links to further documentation, such as [Javadoc for `@KeyFor`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/KeyFor.html).

> I tried haphazardly to sprinkle some @KeyFors here and there, but with a lack of fully understanding what I'm doing it could take a while before I hit the right spots ;-)

Please don't do that!  That way lies suffering.  The manual [tells you not to do that](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#annotate-before-checking); instead, think first and [write specifications](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#get-started-annotations-are-a-specification) that describe your code.

Here are three `@KeyFor` annotations that you culd write:

```
interface IMap extends Iterable<@KeyFor("this") Object> {
...
    default IMap remove(@KeyFor("this") Object key) {
...
    @SuppressWarnings("keyfor") // a key for `contents` is a key for this object
    public java.util.Iterator<@KeyFor("this") Object> iterator() {
```

These annotations state, respectively:

1. The iterator returns keys for this object.
2. Clients must pass a key for this object.
3. The iterator returns keys for this object.  I suppressed a warning because this object acts as a wrapper for a contained object, and I don't recall that the Checker Framework has a way to say, "This object is a wrapper around a field and each of its methods has the same properties as the methods of that field."

The result type-checks without problems (except the nullness one noted in the first section of this answer):

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.KeyFor;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

interface IMap extends Iterable<@KeyFor("this") Object> {
    @Nullable Object get(Object o);
    IMap put(Object key, Object value); // immutable put
    IMap empty();

    default IMap remove(@KeyFor("this") Object key) {
        IMap tmp = empty();

        for (Object k : this) {
            if (!k.equals(key)) {
                tmp.put(k, get(k)); // get(k) is always non-null because of the key iterator
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }
}

class Map implements IMap {
    java.util.Map<Object, Object> contents = new java.util.HashMap<>();

    public Map() {}

    private Map(java.util.Map<Object, Object> contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable Object get(Object key) {
        return contents.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public IMap empty() {
        return new Map();
    }

    @Override
    public IMap put(Object key, Object value) {
        java.util.Map<Object, Object> newContents = new java.util.HashMap<>();
        newContents.putAll(contents);
        newContents.put(key, value);
        return new Map(newContents);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("keyfor") // a key for `contents` is a key for this object
    public java.util.Iterator<@KeyFor("this") Object> iterator() {
        return contents.keySet().iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: there is currently no EnsuresNonNullIf spec I could add to the iterator() method to say something about the call to `get` when it is given KeyFor("this")

Comment: That is correct.  The contract for `get` is a bit more complicated than can be expressed in the Nullness Checker's surface syntax currently.  That's why it is hard-coded.

Comment: Ok thanks @mernst. I'll go and think of what to do for the real much more complex code now. Rewrite a lot of loops, or put asserts or pull request for the CF 

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the informative accepted answer:

1. There is no way to annotate the given code example such that the semantic relation between the iterator and the get method of IMap can be specified to the Checker Framework;
2. As a result the current reported error requires an local non-nullness assert, a rewrite of the code which avoids a key iterator or a SuppressWarning annotation.
3. An extension to the checker framework would be necessary, among the lines of how it was special-cased for java.util.Map, if we want to avoid these workarounds.